# Logout Hook Action not executing?

Tags: action, hook, liferay, logout

I have written a liferay hook for `pre-logout` action. It works fine in my local environment but when I deploy on the server, it doesn't work.

Firstly, the property is not overridden while using configuration in `portal.properties`. Though after adding portal-ext.properties in main liferay application, I can see the property being overridden. But while running the `hook`, it is not executed.

Looking for the solution desperately.

**Environment:** Liferay 6.1.0 CE

Comment: Which version of liferay are you using. Try undeploying the portlet first(Remove from the webapps folder), clear the temp and work folder and then do a deployment.

Comment: Its Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.0 CE both in development and production. I have already tried undeploying the hook and redeploying, it doesn't work.

Comment: Sometimes portlets, hooks etc can get in a muddle when being hot deployed, so have you tried restarting your server?

Comment: Yes I have tried restarting server also....

Comment: @shakeelstha Can you provide some code and/or the steps you followed to create this hook. Thanks

Comment: How can you see that the property is not overridden? Have you set a breakpoint in your pre-logout hook? What does your hook implementation look like?